# How to set linecolor for linechart using coreplot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I am using coreplot 0.9 .I had tried setting linecolor property for CPTLineStyle by

```
CPTLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor=[UIColor grayColor];
```

But it is giving error that linecolor is readonly property. Please give me some solution for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's another line style type object named, helpfully enough, `CPTMutableLineStyle`.

That's where you can set your line color.